# Sheets - Custom Data Validation Combobox

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation, google-sheets-named-ranges

I am having a problem with making my own custom data validation combobox, here is what I am having a problem with:

Sheet (Hardware) `Column A` `Column S`:

Column A = Asset Tag

Column S = is Owned? Yes/No

Sheet (Assigned_Hardware) `Column F`:

Column F = Asset Tag

Now, what I want is for the `Assigned_Hardware 'F'` to display all the items listed from `Hardware 'A'` after confirming the value of `Hardware 'S'`is `No`.

I am a total noob with the Google Sheet and Excel. I can only do simple range combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a data validation dropdown using a custom formula such as query or filter.

However, there is a workaround:

- create the relevant query/filter on another sheet,
- refer to the data range created by the query/filter when you create the Data validation.

---

**Example:**

- create a sheet called, say, "Validation_data".

  - in cell A1, enter "Assigned_Hardware-Asset Type" to identify the purpose of the validation. (This is purely for identification.)
  - in cell A2, enter this formula
    `=query({Hardware!A2:A,Hardware!S2:S},"select Col1 where Col2 = 'No'")`.
    This creates a range ("A2:A") that will contain all the Asset Tags where the asset is not owned.
- in Sheet "Assigned_Hardware", Cell F2 (or whatever cell you choose to use), create the Data Validation:

  - Select Data, Data Validation

    - Criteria: List from a Range
    - Range = "Validation_data!A2:A" (you can select it with the mouse)
    - Save the Data Validation.

Note: a valid alternative might be to create a named range for the query, such as:

- `=query(<<create name range on the Hardware tab>>,"select A, S where S = 'No'",1).`

---

**Note:**

Even though the reference to the data range on "Validation_data" is open-ended, Google Sheets will convert it to include the last row on the "Validation_data" sheet (e.g. "Validation_data!A2:A1000"). Depending on the number of assets, you may wish to reduce the number of rows on "Validation_data" to avoid blowout.

Comment: I marked this correct. Thanks! However, I just edited your post for reference. I edited the =query part.

Comment: Thanks, I note you said the "query part wouldn't work". Is that literally true; or perhaps it is a consequence of different locales where one user must use a "comma", and another, a "semi-colon".

Comment: I think it's not, it's just the select part of the query, it needs to provide the given columns before the ```where``` clause. I did it like this, ```"select A, S where S = 'No',1"```. And I just ***created a new named range*** for my Hardware table where it includes my ```S``` column and replace your ```Hardware!A2:A,Hardware!S2:S```

Comment: _ it needs to provide the given columns before the where clause_ FWIW, you could have done the same thing with `select Col1, Col2 where Col2 = 'No'`. At the risk of telling you what you may already know, the curly brackets in the query have the effect of combining Column A and Column S as two separate ranges, each accessible to the query. Anyway, your edit is fine. PS: Sorry, I managed to lose your actual edit, I hope what I substituted meets your approval.

Comment: No problem. I was able to get my answer because of your answer. You gave me idea on what and how to do it.